# What does this ANR mean?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-anr-dialog

I have enabled StrictMode and captured this log(/data/anr/traces.txt). The issue is that the listview is hanging after processing about 3 rows(on the 4th row). I am using the holder pattern. The list view everywhere else seems to be working fine.

Any help is appreciated.

```
JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=320

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ddbca8 self=0x41dca3c8
  | sysTid=22827 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075642708
  | state=S schedstat=( 38273640000 1091756000 67689 ) utm=3677 stm=150 core=1
  at android.view.View.getContext(View.java:~8153)
  at android.view.View.getLayoutDirection(View.java:6247)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.getRelatedView(RelativeLayout.java:997)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.getRelatedViewBaseline(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.alignBaseline(RelativeLayout.java:642)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:519)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1870)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=22 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42852b80 self=0x68644920
  | sysTid=22961 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1751403896
  | state=S schedstat=( 581366000 108708000 6378 ) utm=40 stm=18 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x428790f8> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=22 (AsyncTask #2)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"OkHttp ConnectionPool" daemon prio=5 tid=16 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x427d6790 self=0x68523a28
  | sysTid=22927 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1750220416
  | state=S schedstat=( 7097000 2266000 145 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4284f478> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=16 (OkHttp ConnectionPool)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Found the problem. 
The stack trace offers some clues alignBase(). What was happening was that the alignment was based on a widget that was NOT visible and referring itself. So main thread went into a suspend state.

Comment: Application not responding

Comment: Found the problem and will update the post so its available for others to see it.

Comment: @user2997127 - please post your solution as an answer and then accept it in a few days when allowed to, so that the question shows as resolved.  (Or, if you feel that the issue was completely unique and will never help anyone else, you can delete the question, but then you won't accumulate any reputation from resolving your problem)

Comment: @ChrisStratton answered my own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The stack trace offers some clues, alignBase() call. What was happening was that the alignment was based on a widget(ratingbar) that was NOT visible and referring itself. So main thread went into a suspend state.

Stacktrace is quite helpful and once you know how to read it, its all about tracing back to where in your code that call might be from. In my case, it was a little involved because all the classes involved were android.

Answer (score 0):

i.e. Application Not Responding ...

If you are trying the task that takes long time for execution(e.g Download images/data from remote server) on main(UI) thread then this ANR occurs

To get rid of this try to use asyntask/thread for these long running tasks.

Comment: We are using Async tasks and all network calls are on a different threads. The stacktrace above does'nt reflect any network calls but view.getContext().